# WPF value on listbox unreadable / using powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell

I'm scripting on powershell and i use WPF on visual studio to had a script more userfriendly and i find it cool.

I finish my powershell script and my xml wpf too.

However when i get my value on my list box, the value are invisible, when my mouse is over the list box, the list box looks populated but this is unreadble.

```
WPF
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Migrate_Storage_CLU_Hyper_v"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Migration Storage Cluster Hyper-v" Height="884" Width="820" WindowState="Normal" ResizeMode="CanResize" MinHeight="745" MinWidth="820" MaxHeight="755" MaxWidth="820">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-6">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="722*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="161*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Name="Label_Cluster_Hyper_v" Content="Cluster Hyper-v :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Height="26" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Host_Hyper_v" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="14,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="296" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label Name="Label_VMs" Content="Virtuals Machines :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="10,228,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_VMs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="445" Margin="14,267,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label Name="Label_Storage_Path_Src" Content="Storage Path source :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="10,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Storage_Path_Src" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="14,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Ok" Content="OK" Margin="558,685,134,1" Grid.Column="1" MinHeight="35" MinWidth="91" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Cancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="666,685,27,1" Grid.Column="1" MinHeight="35" MinWidth="91"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Selected_VMs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="379" Margin="446,267,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="293" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Name="Label_Selected_VMs" Content="Selected Virtuals Machines :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="442,233,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Add" Grid.Column="1" Content=">" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="403,351,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="36" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Remove" Grid.Column="1" Content="&gt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="403,431,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="36" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Check" Content="Check" Margin="454,685,240,1" Grid.Column="1" MinHeight="35" MinWidth="91"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Display_VMs" Grid.Column="1" Content="Display VM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="105,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" FontWeight="Normal" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontSize="10"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Storage_Path_Dst" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="442,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Name="Label_Storage_Path_Dst" Content="Storage Path destination :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="439,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Node_Hyper_v" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="445,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="296" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Name="Label_Node_Hyper_v" Content=" Node Hyper-v :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="440,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Height="26" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Show_Node" Grid.Column="1" Content="Show Node" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="339,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" FontWeight="Normal" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Show_Path" Grid.Column="1" Content="Show Path" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="359,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" FontWeight="Normal" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
Powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework


#########################################################################
###########################***___Function___***##########################

function Get-Check {
   
    if (($Window.Findname("Listbox_Host_Hyper_v").SelectedItems -eq $null) -or ($Window.Findname("Listbox_Selected_VMs").Items -eq $null) -or ($Window.Findname("Listbox_Storage_Path").Items -eq $null) )
       {
        $Window.FindName("Label_EmptyField").Visibility ="Visible"
        $Window.FindName("Button_Ok").IsEnabled = $False
        $Window.FindName("Label_Resume").Visibility ="Hidden"
       }
         else 
             {
             $Window.FindName("Button_Ok").IsEnabled = $True
             $Window.FindName("Label_EmptyField").Visibility ="Hidden"
             $Window.FindName("Label_Resume").Visibility ="Visible"
             $Window.FindName("Label_Resume").Content = "
             Hôte Hyper-V = $Selected_Host
             Chemin UNC = $Selected_UNCPATH
             VM(s) sélectionné = $Selected_Virtuals
             CSV = 
        
             "
             }

                    }
#########################################################################
#############################***___Variable___***#############################

#$global:Host_Hyper_v = Get-Cluster -Domain mydomain.lan | Where-object {$_.name -like "srv[1-9]*"}
#$global:Selected_UNCPATH = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Storage_Path").SelectedItems)
#$global:Selected_Host = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Host_Hyper_v").SelectedItems)
#$global:Selected_Virtuals = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Selected_VMs").SelectedItems)
#$global:Vm_On_Host = Get-VM -ClusterObject (Get-ClusterResource -Cluster $Selected_Host | where ResourceType -eq "Virtual Machine")
#$global:Dst_path = ((Get-ClusterSharedVolume -Cluster $Selected_Host).SharedVolumeInfo).FriendlyVolumeName | Where-object {$_ -like '*NB_*'}
#$global:Src_path = ((Get-ClusterSharedVolume -Cluster $Selected_Host).SharedVolumeInfo).FriendlyVolumeName | Where-object {$_ -notlike '*NB_*'}
#$global:Selected_Node = (Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $Selected_Host).name
#$global:Selected_Dst_Path = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Storage_Path_Dst").SelectedItems)

#########################################################################
#############################***___XML___***#############################
[xml]$XML = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="Migration Storage Cluster Hyper-v" Height="760" Width="820" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="CanResize" MinHeight="745" MinWidth="820" MaxHeight="755" MaxWidth="820">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="722*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="161*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Name="Label_Cluster_Hyper_v" Content="Cluster Hyper-v :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Height="26" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Host_Hyper_v" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="14,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="296" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label Name="Label_VMs" Content="Virtuals Machines :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="10,228,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_VMs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="445" Margin="14,267,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label Name="Label_Storage_Path_Src" Content="Storage Path source :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="10,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Storage_Path_Src" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="14,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Ok" Content="OK" Margin="558,685,134,1" Grid.Column="1" MinHeight="35" MinWidth="91" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Cancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="666,685,27,1" Grid.Column="1" MinHeight="35" MinWidth="91"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Selected_VMs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="379" Margin="446,267,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="293" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Name="Label_Selected_VMs" Content="Selected Virtuals Machines :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="442,233,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Add" Grid.Column="1" Content=">" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="403,351,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="36" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Remove" Grid.Column="1" Content="&gt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="403,431,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="36" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Check" Content="Check" Margin="454,685,240,1" Grid.Column="1" MinHeight="35" MinWidth="91"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Display_VMs" Grid.Column="1" Content="Display VM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="105,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" FontWeight="Normal" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontSize="10"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Storage_Path_Dst" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="442,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Name="Label_Storage_Path_Dst" Content="Storage Path destination :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="439,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <ListBox Name="Listbox_Node_Hyper_v" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="445,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="296" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Name="Label_Node_Hyper_v" Content=" Node Hyper-v :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="440,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Height="26" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Show_Node" Grid.Column="1" Content="Show Node" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="339,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" FontWeight="Normal" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
        <Button Name="Button_Show_Path" Grid.Column="1" Content="Show Path" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="359,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" FontWeight="Normal" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.181" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$FormXML = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XML)
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($FormXML)


#########################################################################
###########################***___Button___***##########################

#Setup Check button
$Window.FindName("Button_Check").add_click({
Get-Check         
})

#Setup Cancel button 
$Window.FindName("Button_Cancel").add_click({
$Window.Close()
})

#Setup List Cluster Hyper-V 
$global:Selected_Host = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Host_Hyper_v").SelectedItems)
$global:Host_Hyper_v = Get-Cluster -Domain mydomain.lan | Where-object {$_.name -like "srv[1-9]*"}
Foreach ($element in $Host_Hyper_v){
$Window.FindName("Listbox_Host_Hyper_v").Items.add($($element.Name)) | Out-Null
}

#Setup List Node Hyper-V 


#Setup List UNC Path source
#Foreach ($element in $Src_Path){
#$Window.FindName("Listbox_Storage_Path").Items.add($($element.Name)) | Out-Null
#}

#Setup List UNC Path destination
Foreach ($element in $Dst_Path){
$Window.FindName("Listbox_Storage_Path_Dst").Items.add($($element.Name)) | Out-Null
}

#Setup Button Display VM
$Window.FindName("Button_Display_VMs").add_click({
$global:Selected_Host = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Host_Hyper_v").SelectedItems)
$global:Vm_On_Host = Get-VM -ClusterObject (Get-ClusterResource -Cluster $Selected_Host | where ResourceType -eq "Virtual Machine")
Foreach ($element in $VM_On_Host){
$Window.FindName("Listbox_VMs").Items.add($($element.Name)) | Out-Null
}})

#Setup Button Show Node
$Window.FindName("Button_Show_Node").add_click({
$global:Selected_Host = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Host_Hyper_v").SelectedItems)
$global:Selected_Node = (Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $Selected_Host).name
Foreach ($element in $Selected_Node){
$Window.FindName("Listbox_Node_Hyper_v").Items.add($($element.Name)) | Out-Null
}})

#Setup Button Show Path
$Window.FindName("Button_Show_Path").add_click({
$global:Selected_Host = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Host_Hyper_v").SelectedItems)
$global:Selected_Node = (Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $Selected_Host).name
$global:Src_path = ((Get-ClusterSharedVolume -Cluster $Selected_Host).SharedVolumeInfo).FriendlyVolumeName | Where-object {$_ -notlike '*NB_*'}
$global:Dst_path = ((Get-ClusterSharedVolume -Cluster $Selected_Host).SharedVolumeInfo).FriendlyVolumeName | Where-object {$_ -like '*NB_*'}
Foreach ($element in $Dst_path){
$Window.FindName("Listbox_Storage_Path_Dst").Items.add($($element.Name)) | Out-Null
}
Foreach ($element in $Src_path){
$Window.FindName("Listbox_Storage_Path_Src").Items.add($($element.Name)) | Out-Null
}})


#Setup Button Add
$Window.FindName("Button_Add").add_click({
$VMs = $($Window.FindName("Listbox_VMs").SelectedItems)
Foreach ($element in $VMs){
$Window.FindName("Listbox_SelectedVMs").Items.add($element) | Out-Null
$Window.FindName("Listbox_VMs").Items.remove($element) | Out-Null
$Window.UpdateLayout() 
}
})

#Setup Button Remove
$Window.FindName("Button_Remove").add_click({
$Server = $($Window.FindName("Listbox_SelectedVMs").SelectedItems)
Foreach ($element in $Server){
$Window.FindName("Listbox_VMs").Items.add($element) | Out-Null
$Window.FindName("Listbox_SelectedVMs").Items.remove($element) | Out-Null
$Window.UpdateLayout() 
}
})

#Setup OK button
$Window.FindName("Button_OK").add_click({
$global:Selected_Host = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Host_Hyper_v").SelectedItems)
$global:Selected_Virtuals = $($Window.Findname("Listbox_Selected_VMs").SelectedItems)
$global:Selected_Node = (Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $Selected_Host).name
$global:Dst_path = ((Get-ClusterSharedVolume -Cluster $Selected_Host).SharedVolumeInfo).FriendlyVolumeName | Where-object {$_ -like '*PS_*'}

foreach ($element in $Selected_Virtuals){

Move-VMStorage `
    ComputerName $element `
    DestinationStoragePath $Selected_Dst_Path`
    Name $element
    }
})

#########################################################################
#########################***___OPEN-WINDOWS___***########################


$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

I try to resize on visual studio the differents windows change many lines who are change on the actually code but can't understand why the value looks like invisible.

Thnks for your help.

Best regards.

A beginner

Comment: When my mouse is over the list box, they are a highlight blue thin line.

Comment: Which `ListBox` is "unreadable"? There are several in the code you have posted. Please provide a *minimal* sample of your issue.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set set the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` something like this:

```
$items = (Get-Cluster ...
$listBox.ItemsSource = $items
```